# Application failed to work in offline explorer

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging, offline, explorer

I have an application build using asp.net in sharepoint platform, however the paging and sorting features in gridview failed to function properly in Offline Explorer (Metaproduct) environment, an offline browsing software.

anyone have encounter the same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have understood your question correctly and you are using something similar to google gears. Paging cannot work offline.

The concept of paging is where data is retrieved from the server 'as required' rather then when the page is loaded - which obviously cannot work if you are offline.

Without seeing any code its hard to provide specific advice but basically you would want to make sure that the page that is being loaded contains all the data necessary for the gridview to display. This would be done by either rendering the gridview straight away with all data or alternatively loading the data into a javascript array.